# Early-Fusion Model for Image Classification with problems evaluating accuracy

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I have a `VGG19` trained with 224x224x3 images for binary classification using `flow_from_dataframe` and a `Places365` TensorFlow-version network that are combined to create a new model.

When I have to evaluate this new model I think I need an `ImageDataGenerator` with a `flow_from_dataframe` to access the images and their labels in a `.csv` file (Total of 400 images), but then I have the following error:

```
ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer 'vgg19' (type Functional).
Input 0 of layer "block1_conv1" is incompatible with the layer: expected min_ndim=4, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (None, None)
```

The `VGG19` is receiving the same image format as when it was trained, so I don't really understand why this is happening.

The class for the `Places365` model:

```
from __future__ import division, print_function
import os
import pickle
import warnings
import numpy as np

from keras import backend as K
from keras.layers import Input
from keras.layers import Activation, Dense, Flatten
from keras.layers import MaxPooling2D
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Conv2D
from keras.regularizers import l2
from keras.layers import Dropout
from keras.layers import GlobalAveragePooling2D
from keras.layers import GlobalMaxPooling2D
from keras.utils import get_source_inputs
from keras.utils import get_file

from keras.preprocessing import image
from keras.applications.imagenet_utils import preprocess_input

WEIGHTS_PATH = 'https://github.com/GKalliatakis/Keras-VGG16-places365/releases/download/v1.0/vgg16-places365_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels.h5'
WEIGHTS_PATH_NO_TOP = 'https://github.com/GKalliatakis/Keras-VGG16-places365/releases/download/v1.0/vgg16-places365_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels_notop.h5'


def VGG16_Places365(weights='places', 
                    input_shape=None,
                    pooling=None,
                    classes=365):


    img_input = Input(shape=input_shape)


    # Block 1
    x = Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, strides=(1, 1), padding='same',
               kernel_regularizer=l2(0.0002),
               activation='relu', name='block1_conv1_365')(img_input)

    x = Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, strides=(1, 1), padding='same',
               kernel_regularizer=l2(0.0002),
               activation='relu', name='block1_conv2_365')(x)

    x = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2), name="block1_pool_365", padding='valid')(x)

    # Block 2
    x = Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=3, strides=(1, 1), padding='same',
               kernel_regularizer=l2(0.0002),
               activation='relu', name='block2_conv1_365')(x)

    x = Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=3, strides=(1, 1), padding='same',
               kernel_regularizer=l2(0.0002),
               activation='relu', name='block2_conv2_365')(x)

    x = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2), name="block2_pool_365", padding='valid')(x)

    # Block 3
    x = Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=3, strides=(1, 1), padding='same',
               kernel_regularizer=l2(0.0002),
               activation='relu', name='block3_conv1_365')(x)

    x = Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=3, strides=(1, 1), padding='same',
               kernel_regularizer=l2(0.0002),
               activation='relu', name='block3_conv2_365')(x)

    x = Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=3, strides=(1, 1), padding='same',
               kernel_regularizer=l2(0.0002),
               activation='relu', name='block3_conv3_365')(x)

    x = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2), name="block3_pool_365", padding='valid')(x)

    # Block 4
    x = Conv2D(filters=512, kernel_size=3, strides=(1, 1), padding='same',
               kernel_regularizer=l2(0.0002),
               activation='relu', name='block4_conv1_365')(x)

    x = Conv2D(filters=512, kernel_size=3, strides=(1, 1), padding='same',
               kernel_regularizer=l2(0.0002),
               activation='relu', name='block4_conv2_365')(x)

    x = Conv2D(filters=512, kernel_size=3, strides=(1, 1), padding='same',
               kernel_regularizer=l2(0.0002),
               activation='relu', name='block4_conv3_365')(x)

    x = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2), name="block4_pool_365", padding='valid')(x)

    # Block 5
    x = Conv2D(filters=512, kernel_size=3, strides=(1, 1), padding='same',
               kernel_regularizer=l2(0.0002),
               activation='relu', name='block5_conv1_365')(x)

    x = Conv2D(filters=512, kernel_size=3, strides=(1, 1), padding='same',
               kernel_regularizer=l2(0.0002),
               activation='relu', name='block5_conv2_365')(x)

    x = Conv2D(filters=512, kernel_size=3, strides=(1, 1), padding='same',
               kernel_regularizer=l2(0.0002),
               activation='relu', name='block5_conv3_365')(x)

    x = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2), name="block5_pool_365", padding='valid')(x)


    inputs = img_input

    # Create model.
    model = Model(inputs, x, name='vgg16-places365')

    # load weights
    weights_path = get_file('vgg16-places365_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels_notop.h5',
                                WEIGHTS_PATH_NO_TOP,
                                cache_subdir='models')

    model.load_weights(weights_path)

    return model
```

The pre-trained model loading and the other methods:

```
import pandas as pd
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras.metrics import Precision, Recall
from tensorflow.keras import losses

model_vgg16_places365 = VGG16_Places365(weights='places', input_shape=(224, 224, 3))

def valid_generator(target_image_size, valid_dataset, valid_images_location):
 valid_data_gen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
 batch_size = 32
 valid_generator_1 = valid_data_gen.flow_from_dataframe(
       target_size=target_image_size,
       dataframe=valid_dataset,
       directory=valid_images_location,
       x_col="id",
       y_col="T1",
       batch_size=batch_size
   )

 valid_generator_2 = valid_data_gen.flow_from_dataframe(
       target_size=target_image_size,
       dataframe=valid_dataset,
       directory=valid_images_location,
       x_col="id",
       y_col="T1",
       batch_size=batch_size
   )

 custom_generator = zip(valid_generator_1, valid_generator_2)

 return custom_generator
```

```
vgg19_model_location = 'vgg19_trained.keras'
vgg19_model = load_model(vgg19_model_location)

combined_model = Model(inputs=[model_vgg16_places365.input, vgg19_model.input], outputs=vgg19_model.output)

combined_model.compile(loss=losses.BinaryCrossentropy(),
                optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=0.0001),
                metrics=
                 ['accuracy',
                  Precision(),
                  Recall()])

valid_dataset = pd.read_csv('valset.csv')
valid_images_location = 'val-images/'
target_image_size = (224,224)
evaluation = combined_model.evaluate(valid_generator(target_image_size, valid_dataset, valid_images_location))
```